# Index of Content on a Defunct Website/Blog

Tags: cache

Is there a way to find the content on a defunct website or blog?
How do you find the content that was on a website from two or three years back?

Google cache doesn't appear to hold information from that long ago.
I've used Wayback machine, but the content they show is limited -- on less popular sites/blogs sometimes there is no content at all.

Does anyone know of other sources, aside from Wayback Machine that can show me the content that was on a now defunct (taken down 1-5 years ago) website or blog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Archive.org](http://www.archive.org/) holds the most complete archive of historical Web content. Their [Wayback Machine](http://wayback.archive.org/web/) search tool provides access to around 2,000 terabytes of compressed archived content, and the archive grows at around [20 terabytes a month](http://www.archive.org/about/faqs.php#9).

Sadly, this means that if you can't find an old defunct site on there, there's a good chance you won't be able to access it anywhere else. Before you give up:

- Try the [Warrick web page recovery tool](http://warrick.cs.odu.edu/), which attempts to reconstruct pages by using combined caches from archive.org, Google, and Bing.
- Try the [other web archive services listed on Netpreserve's archive list page,](http://www.netpreserve.org/about/archiveList.php) most of which focus on websites for one particular country.
- If the page was ever featured on [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/) (search using the box at the foot of every page), try the http://fireballed.org/ mirror/archive service (a long-shot, but worth mentioning).
- Consider searching for the content on a completely separate domain. If it was syndicated, quoted from, or just plain ripped, there's a chance the written content might still exist online somewhere. If you have a rough idea of the blog post titles (or the name of the author), search for them in quotes and see what you find.
- Consider approaching the site owner for the old content if you can.